# How to add Font Awesome icon into <input> button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add an `<input type="reset">` with a Font Awesome icon.

I can achieve this with a hyperlink or button but if I go down that route I need to use jQuery/JS to clear the form, which I'm trying to avoid for the time being.

I'm curious to whether it's possible to achieve the same results. Please see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6s58Luj/) to see what I mean.

```html
Input Reset:
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Clear</input>

<br/>
<br/>

Button:
<button class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Clear</button>

<br/>
<br/>

Anchor:
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Clear</a>
```

If there's no other way I will implement a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`<input>` is self-closing tag, it's not allowed to have any other elements inside it.

Here are all the 3 possible options of doing it as **inline** icon.

**[JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vdfcf9k7/)**

**1.** wrap the `<i>` and `<input>` button into a `<span>` tag, with some custom styles.

```
<span class="btn btn-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> <input type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</span>

span > i {
    color: white;
}
span > input {
    background: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

**2.** use `<button type="reset">` - ***recommended***.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" type="reset">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Clear
</button>
```

**3.** use `<a>` anchor tag + javascript

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myform').reset();" class="btn btn-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Clear
</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

https://jsfiddle.net/a6s58Luj/3/

```
<input type="reset" class="NEWCLASS btn btn-warning" value="&#xf00d; Clear" />
```

By adding `value="&#xf00d; Clear"` you can add the X icon. `f00d` is the icon HEX/whatever, which I got from inspecting the elements (checking the `::before`'s content). You might have to look into some additional styling, but it will work. Just remember to set the font.

Comment: Oh, you also don't have to use the NEWCLASS class I created. It was just to tell a difference from the rest of the buttons.

Comment: Spot on Snorlax thank you. I just need to work out how to use my default font on the button as well as the font awesome font. Notice how it's stripped the style.

Comment: That's what I saw as well. Unfortunately, I am 99.9% positive that you won't be able to do that. You can't do "only do half the text in one font and the other half in another font". That won't work. It's an interesting type of button, but I would do it with jQuery in a heartbeat.

Comment: That is very clever way of doing it, by the way make sure to test if the FontAwesome font doesn't cause any other issues for displaying the normal text.

Comment: Yep. You might want to change the `font-family` to `font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;` just like in the original one.

Comment: Yeah I can't do it, decided to go for the jQuery solution. Seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me combining fa classes and unicode inside the input tag

```
 <input type='button' class='btn btn-default fas fa-share-alt' style='background-color:white; color:black;' value='&#xf0c5; Copy' onclick='myFunctionCopy($x)'>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this inside a form, you cant make `type="reset"`.

The best method I would say is, wrap the input element with label and apply all CSS to label. Any click on label will trigger input element also.

```html
<label classname="all css of your button">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>  
</label>
```