# Bootstrap input button not render with color

Tags: html, forms, input, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I wish to add a font awesome icon beside my `input` button.

So, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30577873/7766525) and only option 1 apply to my use case since I need to submit a form to delete repository.

But the `input` button does not match the color of `span` tag.

I tried to add `btn-danger` class into `input` tag but it has shadow.

https://jsfiddle.net/coolwei/4osuyrk5/6/

What I want to achieve is a consistent color and button size with View and Add button.

Comment: I do not understand why you are creating an input inside a button, can you please explain?

Comment: @Will thanks, I'll change it. Because I take over my senior project and enhance it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use `<button>` tag.

However, if you **really** have to do this that way, you should clear default input styles like this:

```css
.clear-input {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

And add this class to your input

```html
<input class="clear-input" type="submit" value="Delete">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2vdabphn/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're nesting a `button` inside an `a` here.

```
<a href="#">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mr-1">
  <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
  Add Student
  </button>
</a>
```

For your submit button, what you want to do is use the `button` tag with the `type="submit"` property.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
  <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
  Delete
</button>
```

Comment: I take over my senior project and enhance. Thank you for pointing it out.